# PPCore.dll crashes while playing powerpoint in webbrowser using C#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, powerpoint

I have a C# application, in which I am playing PowerPoint files (pptx, ppt, ppxs, pps extensions) using web browser control in C#. Multiple powerpoints are lined up back to back for playback. But, sometimes it plays very well, sometimes it throws the pop up box with error "PowerPoint stopped working" with fault module ppcore.dll. I have tested this on Microsoft Office 2007 and 2010 and in both this problem occurs. Sometimes this popup comes within few minutes after application gets started and sometimes after couple of hours.

Do anybody knows what would be the problem and how to solve this.